# What is the meaning of robustness in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, robust

What is the meaning of robustness in machine learning? What is the relationship between robust and bias/variance?

Answer (score 2):

Based on my experience, robust usually means protection to misspecifications or anomalies (e.g. outliers). For example, if we had some sample data and wanted to perform a linear regression, a least squares approach would not be robust to outlying points (e.g. an outlier can really break down the fit). Some robust approaches might include M-estimation which some particular choice of "psi function" to downweight observations with large residuals in the $y$ direction. Perhaps some high breakdown methods could be used such as least median squares. Typically robust methods would have more bias (ignoring some features of the data, particularly the outliers) but less variability (not relying on the misspecifications or anomalies).